# split string return different result

Tags: .net, vb.net, split

I have a problem to split text

```
Dim strText as String = "Listings/Listing"
Dim separator as String = "Listings/"
Dim arr as string() = strText.split(separator)
```

My code return 3 results

```
arr(0) = ""
arr(1) = "istings/"
arr(2) = "isting"
```

What is the problem? Why is this happening? I need to get a `Listing` from `strText`

Test: http://rextester.com/VNQ39065

Comment: That will not compile using Option Strict.   The easiest thing would be to use string.Replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way instead,

```
 Dim StrText As String = "Listings/Listing"
 Dim arr as string() = Split(StrText, "Listings/")
```

The .split method works differently, and is character based using that particular overload, so it only uses the first "L"c in your separator string.

Comment: `The .split method ... is character based`  Half true.  There are 6 overloads, 3 for Char and 3 for String.  The OP was using the wrong one and Option Strict Off allowed it to compile

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you mean

```
Dim strText as String = "Listings/Listing"
Dim separator as String = "/"
Dim arr as string() = strText.split(separator)

arr(0) = "Listings"
arr(1) = "Listing"
```

Comment: I need split by `Listings/`

Comment: I doesn't make sense. You split a string by separator, and Listings/ isn't separating anything.

Comment: Is correct, what I do not understand is because that happens

Comment: Because you dont have Option Strict on.  The single arg form expects  Char() - so your string is being treated as a collection of seperators not a string.

Comment: @Plutonix,  thanks for reminding me, I was limiting to the particular application. I augmented my answer. Oops.. wrong thread.. oh well.

Answer (score 1):

As another alternative, an alteration to your original to use one of the String() overloads of split will also work, e.g.:

```
Dim strText as String = "Listings/Listing"
Dim separator as String() = {"Listings/"}
Dim arr as string() = strText.split(separator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Result should be:

```
arr(0) = "Listing"
```

See the MSDN documentation for String.Split Method (String(), StringSplitOptions) for more details on usage.  If you use `None` instead of `RemoveEmptyEntries`, you will get back a two-element array with a first element of `String.Empty`.